# Unordered_map to binary file

Tags: c++, c++11

Why I can't write unordered_map structure to a file ?

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, PassLibrary const& data){
    stream << data.local_login << " " //std::string
           << data.local_pass << " "  //std::string
           << data.libs;              //std::unordered_map - error
    return stream;
}
```

Best regards.

Comment: Because there's no overload for `operator<<(std::ostream&, std::unordered_map<K, T, H, KE, A> const&)`. You'd have to write your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know how to print a unordered_map to a file. It's up to you doing it.
As @Barry said you can define the function `operator<<(std::ostream&, std::unordered_map<K, T, H, KE, A> const&)` in order to tell the compiler how to do it. And maybe you also want to intruct <s>him</s> it on how to load it back from file.